# Is there an in-built function in PHP that allows me to select array keys that are not one(s) I have specified

Tags: php, arrays

Consider an array

```
$my_array("key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3")
```

Does PHP have a function in which I can pass in key1 and it returns key2 and key3.
Assuming key1 is always the same but key2 and key3 can change from time to time.

```
$my_array("key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3");
$result = the_function_i_want("key1");
print_r($result);
```

Expected Output

```
 Array
    (
        [key2] => value2
        [key3] => value3
    )
```

Comment: [array_diff_key()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) is what your'e looking for

Comment: Do you want get only keys or key-value pairs?

Comment: if I get the keys then I can easily get the value. I already have a function written that does this, I just wanted to know if PHP has a built in function in order to avoid re-inventing stuff.

Comment: `array_diff_key ($my_array, ['key1'=>1]);`

Comment: i am deleting my answer because OP said he only wants to know that function exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to compare the keys you could use the following;

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("a" => "green");

function key_diff($array1, $array2){

    foreach ($array2 as $sKey => $value) {
        if(isset( $array1[$sKey] ) ) unset($array1[$sKey]);
    }
    return $array1;
}

var_dump(key_diff($array1, $array2));
exit;
```

If you wish to compare the values you can use array_diff() as [Taken from PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Multiple occurrences in $array1 are all treated the same way. This will output :

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: I am afriad he don't want this:-  `Does PHP have a function in which I can pass in key1 and it returns key2 and key3`

Comment: I see, its a key comparison, not a value.. Will look at creating something

Comment: I think what he want is he can pass first key and get all the keys of that array